# Value of input not changed

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

Using Vue3 and Vuex4

I got an input field:

```
<input :class="invalid.includes(item.attribute) ? 'invalidInput' : 'validInput'" type="text" :id="item.attribute" :name="item.attribute" :placeholder="item.default_value" min="0" step="any" :value="item.value" @input="validate(item.attribute, $event)" class="p-1">
```

I change the value of "invalid" like this. Just checking for the validity of a regex and adding/removing the attribute to the array.

```
        VALIDATE_INPUT: (state, data) => {
            var regex = /(?=.*\d)^\$?(([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)|0)?(\.\d{1,2})?$/;

            switch (data.attribute) {
                case 'invoice_amount_f':
                    if (!regex.test(data.value)) {
                        state.validations.push(data.attribute)
                    } else {
                        let index = state.validations.findIndex(el => el === data.attribute);

                        if (index > -1) {
                            state.validations.splice(index, 1);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

The action calling the mutation is called like:

```
        const validate = (attribute, event) => {
            store.dispatch('validate', {
                attribute: attribute,
                value: event.target.value
            });
        }
```

Computed:

```
        var invalid = computed({
            get() {
                return store.getters.getValidationState;
            }
        });
```

When now typing something into the input field the text in the field ain't chaning. This seems to happen cause I use the value of `invalid` inside the template. Why is that?

EDIT: It seems to have something to do with the scope I am using it in.

```
    <h3>{{ invalid }}</h3>
    <div v-if="nestedListItems && Object.keys(nestedListItems).length !== 0">
        <draggable v-model='nestedListItems' item-key="id" class=" w-12/12 bg-white m-auto border" animation="150">
```

When rendering it outside of `draggable` it's absolutely fine. Inside it crashes my store.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an object to the `:class`, see here:
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes

I suggest you create a variable in the script containing the boolean e.g. `isValid` and then apply it like this:

`:class="{invalidInput : !isValid, validInput: isValid }"`

Comment: I am using it like this on other parts and it's working. `invalid.includes` is returning is returning true or false anyways. I also noticed it's not just the style binding. Just placing the `invalid` computed property inside the render context is causing this error.

Comment: `invalid` isn't a reserved word as far as I know, but have you tried to rename it to something else?